# StereoCalibration in OpenCV on Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, camera-calibration, stereo-3d

I am new in OpenCV, and could not find normal tutorial for stereoCalibration on Python. If you have some samples, please share.

I do single calibration for each of cameras, and i have next problem. The left one:[image: left]

The right one:
[image: right]

PS: I'm doing Depth-map and by the metter of it, i received bad map.

UPDATE: I have ported the C++ version from https://github.com/jayrambhia/Vision/blob/master/OpenCV/C%2B%2B/stereocalibrate.cpp
Yeah, it has no error but it return only fully black images
Ported cod:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

print "Welcome\n"

numBoards = 30  #how many boards would you like to find
board_w = 7
board_h = 6

board_sz = (7,6)
board_n = board_w*board_h

# termination criteria
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)

# Arrays to store object points and image points from all the images.
object_points = [] # 3d point in real world space
imagePoints1 = [] # 2d points in image plane.
imagePoints2 = [] # 2d points in image plane.

corners1 = []
corners2 = []

#obj = []
#for j in range(0,board_n):
    #obj.append(np.(j/board_w, j%board_w, 0.0))
obj = np.zeros((6*7,3), np.float32)
obj[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:7,0:6].T.reshape(-1,2)



vidStreamL = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  # index of your camera
vidStreamR = cv2.VideoCapture(1)  # index of your camera
success = 0
k = 0
found1 = False
found2 = False

while (success < numBoards):

   retL, img1 = vidStreamL.read()
   height, width, depth  = img1.shape
   retR, img2 = vidStreamR.read()
   #resize(img1, img1, Size(320, 280));
   #resize(img2, img2, Size(320, 280));
   gray1 = cv2.cvtColor(img1,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
   gray2 = cv2.cvtColor(img2,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

   found1, corners1 = cv2.findChessboardCorners(img1, board_sz)
   found2, corners2 = cv2.findChessboardCorners(img2, board_sz)

   if (found1):
       cv2.cornerSubPix(gray1, corners1, (11, 11), (-1, -1),criteria)
       cv2.drawChessboardCorners(gray1, board_sz, corners1, found1)

   if (found2):
       cv2.cornerSubPix(gray2, corners2, (11, 11), (-1, -1), criteria)
       cv2.drawChessboardCorners(gray2, board_sz, corners2, found2)

   cv2.imshow('image1', gray1)
   cv2.imshow('image2', gray2)

   k = cv2.waitKey(100)
   print k
   if (k == 27):
       break
   if (k == 32 and found1 != 0 and found2 != 0):

       imagePoints1.append(corners1);
       imagePoints2.append(corners2);
       object_points.append(obj);
       print "Corners stored\n"
       success+=1

       if (success >= numBoards):
           break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
print "Starting Calibration\n"
cameraMatrix1 = cv2.cv.CreateMat(3, 3, cv2.CV_64FC1)
cameraMatrix2 = cv2.cv.CreateMat(3, 3, cv2.CV_64FC1)

retval, cameraMatrix1, distCoeffs1, cameraMatrix2, distCoeffs2, R, T, E, F = cv2.stereoCalibrate(object_points, imagePoints1, imagePoints2, (width, height))
## , cv2.cvTermCriteria(cv2.CV_TERMCRIT_ITER+cv2.CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 100, 1e-5),   cv2.CV_CALIB_SAME_FOCAL_LENGTH | cv2.CV_CALIB_ZERO_TANGENT_DIST)
#cv2.cv.StereoCalibrate(object_points, imagePoints1, imagePoints2, pointCounts, cv.fromarray(K1), cv.fromarray(distcoeffs1), cv.fromarray(K2), cv.fromarray(distcoeffs2), imageSize, cv.fromarray(R), cv.fromarray(T), cv.fromarray(E), cv.fromarray(F), flags = cv.CV_CALIB_FIX_INTRINSIC)
#FileStorage fs1("mystereocalib.yml", FileStorage::WRITE);
# fs1 << "CM1" << CM1;
#fs1 << "CM2" << CM2;
# #fs1 << "D1" << D1;
#fs1 << "D2" << D2;
#fs1 << "R" << R;
#fs1 << "T" << T;
#fs1 << "E" << E;
#fs1 << "F" << F;
print "Done Calibration\n"
print "Starting Rectification\n"
R1 = np.zeros(shape=(3,3))
R2 = np.zeros(shape=(3,3))
P1 = np.zeros(shape=(3,3))
P2 = np.zeros(shape=(3,3))

#(roi1, roi2) = cv2.cv.StereoRectify(cameraMatrix1, distCoeffs1, cameraMatrix2, distCoeffs2,(width, height), R, T, R1, R2, P1, P2, Q=None, flags=cv2.cv.CV_CALIB_ZERO_DISPARITY, alpha=-1, newImageSize=(0, 0))
cv2.stereoRectify(cameraMatrix1, distCoeffs1, cameraMatrix2, distCoeffs2,(width, height), R, T, R1, R2, P1, P2, Q=None, flags=cv2.cv.CV_CALIB_ZERO_DISPARITY, alpha=-1, newImageSize=(0,0))
#stereoRectify(cameraMatrix1, distCoeffs1, cameraMatrix2, distCoeffs2,(width, height), R, T)

#fs1 << "R1" << R1;
#fs1 << "R2" << R2;
#fs1 << "P1" << P1;
#fs1 << "P2" << P2;
#fs1 << "Q" << Q;

print "Done Rectification\n"
print "Applying Undistort\n"



map1x, map1y = cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap(cameraMatrix1, distCoeffs1, R1, P1, (width, height), cv2.CV_32FC1)
map2x, map2y = cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap(cameraMatrix2, distCoeffs2, R2, P2, (width, height), cv2.CV_32FC1)

print "Undistort complete\n"

while(True):
    retL, img1 = vidStreamL.read()
    retR, img2 = vidStreamR.read()
    imgU1 = np.zeros((height,width,3), np.uint8)
    imgU1 = cv2.remap(img1, map1x, map1y, cv2.INTER_LINEAR, imgU1, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, 0)
    imgU2 = cv2.remap(img2, map2x, map2y, cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
    cv2.imshow("imageL", img1);
    cv2.imshow("imageR", img2);
    cv2.imshow("image1L", imgU1);
    cv2.imshow("image2R", imgU2);
    k = cv2.waitKey(5);
    if(k==27):
        break;
```

Comment: Use better quality images, stereo disparity requires perfectly horizontal cameras.  It tries to map pixel from left image to pixel in right image and based on distance estimates depth (distance from camera).  noisy images as in your case are horrible for such things.

Comment: In order to have better synchronization between images, you may want to replace the vidStreamL.read() / vidStreamR.read() to vidStreamL.grab() / vidStreamR.grab() / vidStreamL.retrieve() / vidStreamR.retrive(). the grab fixes the data and is fast, the retrieve passes the data from the camera and is slow. read combines them both causing a time gap between images.

Answer (score 1):

P1 and P2 should be size 3,4
when initialized with 3,3 you get them back empty
P1 = np.zeros(shape=(3,4))
P2 = np.zeros(shape=(3,4))